# Permission denied for codebloks

Tags: code-blocks

i have installed code blocks from Ubuntu software Center. When I create a new project and compile it, in the output window it say "`permission denied`". How must I run code blocks, or where should I place the project files to remove this error ?!

Comment: When you created your project, where did you save it?

Comment: Do you mean "permission denied" for the compilation, or for executing the resulting binary file?

Comment: save it in my hard drive

Comment: "permission denied" is for execute able file

Comment: Make sure you save file as with extension for C  e.g file.c and for file.cpp , this resolved issue on Ubuntu 16.04 for CodeBlocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you have selected a codeblocks workspace that is on a non-Linux filesystem (such as an external NTFS hard drive). Such filesystems don't natively support Unix-style permission bits, so there's no way to mark files as executable (except globally, at mount time).

If that is the case here, then the easiest solution is to move your workspace to your regular Linux home directory.

Comment: @Morteza If this solved your issue, please click the checkmark on the left to thank the user, it really helps out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're the owner of the files. If you're not, you can run this:

```
sudo chown usrname:username /path/to/your/file
```

Also make sure it's executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/file
```